# webapi .net core got nginx connect() failed (111: Connection refused)

Tags: c#, ubuntu, nginx, .net-core, kestrel

Deploy my webapi dotnet core project to Ubuntu server 
Configuration with kestrel and proxy via nginx

my code in file `Program.cs`

```
public class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
      .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseConfiguration(config)
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseUrls("http://localhost:5050")
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .Build(); 
    host.Run();
  }
}
```

Created file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and maded symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-enable/default`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

my file in /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-project.service

```
[Unit]
Description=WebApi .NET Core running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/aspnetcore/project
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/project/project.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-project
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For deploy use this script and it's work until this day

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet publish

cp -r /root/src/project/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/* /var/aspnetcore/project/

cp /root/src/project/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/project.dll /var/aspnetcore/project/

service nginx restart
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl stop kestrel-project.service
systemctl enable kestrel-project.service
systemctl start kestrel-project.service
systemctl status kestrel-project.service
```

Now when I launch my webapi on my localhost on pc - webapi work well and answer to my requests, but from server I've got HTTP error 500 and in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I see this

```
2018/02/11 19:58:04 [alert] 10584#10584: aborting
2018/02/11 20:01:15 [error] 11717#11717: *1 connect() failed (111:Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: , request: "GET /list HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.1.1:5050/list", host: "*.*.*.*.*"
```

Please help me to understand this problem and fix it

Without changes webapi work well a long time but a couple of days ago I began to appear these errors

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @JasonThuli I found another way to resolve it, I've add project to docker container and make some changes. I can answer on my own question and explain details - if you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the answer on my question, but I found another way to eradicate the problem

*How to make project great again*

Create new .net Core project Web-Api with Docker support

Copy/Paste code of the project to new project with Docker

And now my code in `Program.cs`

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
}
```

My file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

drop file `/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-project.service`

config Docker in project

My Docker file - use for automatic build on Docker Hub

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5050/tcp

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*5050
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT docker

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5050"]
```

My file Docker.Compose

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5050:80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY project/project.csproj project/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/project
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]
```

sign up on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) *it's free*

Connect to my github account and create automatic build for My project

And then on server side I connect to docker hub

make `docker pull dockerprofile/project`

and then `docker run -d -p 5050:80 dockerprofile/project`

After that everything works fine already 4 months

*ps If you need more details just ask for me*